# Are all MD5 hash codes for different files of the same length?

Tags: encryption

My question is about if all MD5 hash codes for different files have the same length?

Comment: This question shows  a lack of basic understanding of what MD5 actually is and a minimal research by the OP (like looking at wikipedia) would have fixed this. First, it is a hash function and not encryption (i.e. tag is wrong) and second it is defined to always output 128 bit. I think we should expect the OP to do some basic research to know what he is talking about in the first place, therefore downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5):

> The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used hash function producing a 128-bit hash value.

Yes.  Any amount of data you hash with it will give you a 128-bit hash.